# Limit date for each day to 2:30 PM

Tags: sql, oracle

SQL Oracle Query:

I have datetime values in 30 minute intervals.  I want to stop each day at 2:30 PM.

I am limiting my hours with this:

```
TO_CHAR(ALL_DATES.DATEDATE,'HH24') NOT IN (01,02,03,04,05,06,07,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,00)
```

This gives me data from 8 AM to 3 PM.  I need to only have data through 2:30.
Please show me how to do this better.

Comment: What's the datatype of `DATEDATE`, is it a date?

Comment: Thank you Gordon for the edit.

Comment: YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS

Comment: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' is not a data type, it is a format mask.  Data types are like DATE, TIMESTAMP, VARCHAR2, etc.  So again, what is the _datatype_ of your column DATEDATE.

Comment: I'm creating the datetime using this formula:
TRUNC(SYSDATE-2, 'hh') + 30.5 / (24 * 60)/*TO_DATE('2020-07-01')*/ + NUMTODSINTERVAL(ROWNUM*30,'MINUTE')

Comment: Right, but how is the column `ALL_DATES.DATEDATE` defined when you view the table definition? Every column has a datatype (number, varchar2, date, timestamp with local time zone etc). What is the datatype shown next to `DATEDATE`?

Comment: From comments on @dnoeth's answer, it sounds like `DATEDATE` is a `date`. Glad we got there in the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plain Standard SQL, but Oracle chokes on DATEs.

TIMESTAMP datatype:

```
cast(ALL_DATES.DATEDATE as time) between time '08:00:00' and time '14:30:00'
```

DATE datatype:

```
cast(cast(ALL_DATES.DATEDATE as timestamp) as time) between time '08:00:00' and time '14:30:00'
```

Comment: dnoeth, I get this error on your code:ORA-00932:  <br/>
inconsistent datatypes: expected TIME got DATE
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"

Comment: How do I add line breaks to my comments?

Comment: Afaik you can't add line breaks in comments. Regarding the error Oracle seems to choke on DATEs, but works for TIMESTAMPs: `cast(cast(d as timestamp) as time) between time '08:00:00' and time '14:30:00'`

Comment: `time` literals, very interesting - they appear to be [undocumented](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1) but return type 185, which also appears to be undocumented, but can be used for columns in views but not in tables. What does *Oracle chokes on dates* mean, though?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson If the base type is a date casting to time results in this *inconsistent datatypes: expected TIME got DATE* error. Need to cast to timestamp first. Regarding the undocumented type, as Oracle supports DATE & TIMESTAMP literals I simply forgot that it doesn't support TIME :-)

Comment: So strictly speaking, Oracle chokes on `TIME` ;)

Comment: I see what you mean. All `time` operations are undocumented and unsupported though, as far as I know.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson But implemented since at least 11gR2